# Ingesting and compiling multiple fixed width files with a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to write clean code to read and compile multiple files with relatively lower maintenance and improved readability, but I am missing something here.

Namely after updating the file names :

```
#update the names of the infiles
infile1 = 'file1.txt'
infile2 = 'file2.txt'
...
infile4 = 'file4.txt'
```

I would like to turn this working step :

```
# read fixed width file
df1 = pd.read_fwf(infile1,
                header=None,
                widths=[sample widths],
                names=[sample names here]
                )
...
...
df4 = pd.read_fwf(infile4,
                header=None,
                widths=[sample widths],
                names=[sample names here]
                )
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4])
```

where `[sample widths]` and `[sample names here]` are specific to my file and quite lengthy,

into something easier to read and maintain:

```
# DESIRED FORM
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    df\i = pd.read_fwf(f'infile{i}',
                       header=None,
                       widths=[sample widths],
                       names=[sample names here]
                      )
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4])
```

I feel I'm close but am missing something simple here related to how I'm writing my loop. I am getting  this error when I run it

> df\i = pd.read_fwf('infile'f'{i}',
>
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow!

First you could load filenames (or longer path if you need) to a list.
After that set a initial data frame with file_1 data and append the rest of the files into the created dataframe:

```
infiles = ['file_1.txt', ..., 'file_n.txt']
df = pd.read_fwf(infiles[0], header=None, widths=[sample widths], 
        names=[sample names here])

for i in range(1, len(infiles)):
    temp_df = pd.read_fwf(infiles[i], header=None, widths=[sample widths],
        names=[sample names here])
    df.append(temp_df)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm!

Comment: I just wanted to add that I changed the last part of ```df.append(temp_df)``` to ```df=pd.concat([df,temp_df])``` since append did not seem to work for me.